# JS Array.filter() not removing items that return false as it should

Tags: javascript, algorithm, filter, p5.js

I am following along with TheCodingTrain's Wave Collapse Function video, and I am running into a persistent error with the filter function.

This is my code so far:

```
const tiles = [];

let grid = [];

const DIM = 2;

const blank = 0;
const up = 1;
const right = 2;
const down = 3;
const left = 4

const rules = [
  [
    [blank, up],
    [blank, right],
    [blank, down],
    [blank, left]
  ],
  [
    [right, down, left],
    [up, down, left],
    [blank, down],
    [up, right, down]
  ],
  [
    [right, down, left],
    [up, down, left],
    [up, right, left],
    [blank, left]
  ],
  [
    [blank, up],
    [up, down, left],
    [up, right, left],
    [up, right, down]
  ],
  [
    [right, down, left],
    [blank, right],
    [up, right, left],
    [up, right, down]
  ]
];

function preload() {
  tiles[0] = loadImage("blank.png");
  tiles[1] = loadImage("up.png");
  tiles[2] = loadImage("right.png");
  tiles[3] = loadImage("down.png");
  tiles[4] = loadImage("left.png");
}

function checkValid(options, valid) {
  for (let i = options.length - 1; i >- 0; i--) {
    if (!valid.includes(options[i])){
      options.splice(i, 1);
}
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  redraw();
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < DIM * DIM; i++) {
    grid[i] = {
      collapsed: false,
      options: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  //Pick cell with least entropy
  let gridCopy = grid.slice();
  console.table(gridCopy);
  gridCopy = gridCopy.filter((a) => !a.collapsed);
  
  console.table(gridCopy);
  
  gridCopy.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.options.length - b.options.length;
  });
  
  //Filter gridCopy to have only the elements with the lowest entropy
  gridCopy = gridCopy.filter((element) => {
    return element.options.length == gridCopy[0].options.length;
  });
  //Pick a cell, collapse it, then pick an option and set it
  const cell = random(gridCopy);
  cell.collapsed = true;
  const pick = random(cell.options);
  cell.options = [pick];
  
  const w = width / DIM;
  const h = height / DIM;
  
  for (let j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
      let cell = grid[i + j * DIM];
      if (cell.collapsed) {
        let index = cell.options[0];
        image(tiles[index], i * w, j * h, w, h);
      } else {
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        rect(i * w, j * h, w, h);
      }
    }
  }
  
  const nextGrid = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
      let index = i + j * DIM;
      if (grid[index].collapsed) {
        nextGrid[index] = grid[index];
      } else {
        let options = [blank, up, right, down, left];
        //Look up
        if (j > 0) {
          let validOptions = [];
          let UP = grid[i + (j - 1) * DIM];
          for (let option of UP.options) {
            let valid = rules[option][2];
            validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
          }
          checkValid(options, validOptions);
        }
        //Look right
        if (i < DIM - 1) {
          let validOptions = [];
          let RIGHT = grid[i + 1 + j * DIM];
          for (let option of RIGHT.options) {
            let valid = rules[option][3];
            validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
          }
          checkValid(options, validOptions);
        }
        //Look down
        if (j < DIM - 1) {
          let validOptions = [];
          let DOWN = grid[i + (j + 1) * DIM];
          for (let option of DOWN.options) {
            let valid = rules[option][0];
            validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
          }
          checkValid(options, validOptions);
        }
        //Look left
        if (i > 0) {
          let validOptions = [];
          let LEFT = grid[i - 1 + j * DIM];
          for (let option of LEFT.options) {
            let valid = rules[option][1];
            validOptions = validOptions.concat(valid);
          }
          checkValid(options, validOptions);
        }
        nextGrid[index] = {
          options,
          collapsed: false
        };
      }
    }
  }
  
  grid = nextGrid;
  
  noLoop();
}
```

gridCopy.filter((a) => !a.collapsed) should return only the object in gridCopy that have not been collapsed. However, when I run this console shows that the index that is collapsed is never removed. This is causing errors to the tile generation. I've tried setting new variables, filtering as I set the gridCopy equal to grid. Nothing works.

This issue is not related to the console itself to my knowledge, as it seems filter never properly removes the indexes which return true.

Comment: Could you provide a full working example in JS Fiddle? there are things missing from the example so I can't run it.

Comment: @codeguy Apologies, I forgot about the included images. I could not get JSFiddle to load for some reason, but here is a repl.it link to join my repl and view it.
https://replit.com/join/rjirxswvhh-cory-eheart-1